# Github repo url displaying readme.md instead of index.html

Tags: github, github-pages, tailwind-css

My repo on Github is only displaying the readme.md when I open the url. I have my index.html in a public folder along w/ a stylesheet.

I'm using tailwind and I followed along w/ a youtube tutorial video and thats how his setup was. I looked it up and read that the index should be living in the same location as the readme.md, because github pages is deploying the root, I tried moving my html out of the public folder and where the readme.md is and I'm still having the same issue.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, I'm fairly new at coding so I'm sure there's a simple solution to this that I just haven't thought of or know of.

Here is the repo/docs:
https://github.com/RachelNapier/writers_block_landing_page

And here is the repo URL:
https://rachelnapier.github.io/writers_block_landing_page/

Thanks so much, in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use repository root or the `docs` folder to host your index.html, see [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

If you move your files under the `public` folder to the root and configure Github pages to use the root folder under your target branch, it would be ok:

[image]

For instance, I've forked your repo and moved the files accordingly [here](https://github.com/bertrandmartel-bot/writers_block_landing_page), it gives :

https://bertrandmartel-bot.github.io/writers_block_landing_page/

Also, you would need to replace relative links to `../images` by `images/` like [here](https://github.com/RachelNapier/writers_block_landing_page/blob/master/public/index.html#L22)